# conditionly selecting a portion of a dataframe rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
In [75]:

x.head()
Out[75]:
         start    end   phone
  0      0       1600    /
  1      1600    1660    p
  2      1660    1720    e
  3      1720    1780    n
  4      1780    1850    e
```

I have the start number and the end number, and I want to select all rows in-between those numbers. 
For example, for start=0 and end=1720 I will get the first three rows.

I tried the naive way:

```
x[x.start==0:x.end==1720]
```

but of course that didn't work. The cumbersome way did work:

```
s = x[x.start==0].index
e = x[x.end==1720].index
x[s:e]
```

Is there a more elegant way to do that? The way I see it, the problem with pandas is that I can't guess those elegant ways. You simply have to be a pro to do stuff, or the code has to be ugly.

Comment: Do you have the start and end values swapped? Your data doesn't look like it has values where `start >= 1780` and `end <= 1720`, but maybe it's in the data we can't see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that

```
some_start = 0
some_end = 1720
```

Then

```
x[(x.start >= some_start) & (x.end <= some_end)]
```

Note that your approach of finding the index where the `start` value is satisfied and then finding the index where the `end` value is satisfied has some drawbacks. It requires the data to be sorted by both columns and in the right order. It also means there can't be duplicates, or else the `.index` of the location(s) where `x.start==0` is True may not be a single scalar value.

Comment: Thanks, that's half way there. The only problem with this solution is the assumption that the columns are sorted. in my case they are, and that is helpful. but what if the data was not sorted? I would like to select rows from a location where specific condition was met to a point were a different specific condition was met. How would I do that? and also, how do I check that i didnt recieve empty DF?

Comment: I'm confused. My solution should not require the columns to be sorted. Using `x[(x.start >= some_start) & (x.end <= some_end)]` will work, regardless of where it is in the DataFrame that those conditions are met, or even if they are met with duplicate entries.

Comment: For example, suppose that your "start" condition happens in the data frame *after* your "stop" condition. How can you guarantee this doesn't happen? And, if your data *does happen to be sorted* this will *still work* and give you the desired range of data. So when you can make guarantees about the ordering of the two logicals, this would still work. I suppose the case when it could fail is if there are multiple separate ranges of rows that satisfy the start/stop criteria and you just want the first range. If so, you should clarify by re-stating the question.

Comment: Ok, I understand now what your code does. it doesnt metter the original order of the rows. It is only looking for rows in which the condition you set is met, no metter if they come one after the other. This is good for my need at the moment, but in general i would still want to know the answer to my original question. For example, When I change both conditions to == instead of =<, then it is not working. Im looking for a way to select a portion of rows _as_they_appear_on_the_df from one location (set by cond) to other location (set by other cond)

Comment: But if you use the condition "==" it is not logically the same. Do you want an interface that lets you identify a single row? Or do you want an interface that lets you supply a logical condition that must be true for a range of rows? They are very different concepts.

Comment: My point of view would be that if you express this as "Find the single row where Condition 1 is True. Now find the single row where Condition 2 is true. Now get all the rows between them" then that is an incorrect way to approach it unless you can document the guarantees about the data. A better approach is "Along dimension 1, what condition should be true? Along dimension 2, what condition should be true? Now take the intersection of the sets of rows where those are true."

Comment: Until I'll find a counter example, Accepted :)